# NSDate subtracting trouble

Tags: ios, nsdate

so in my app I want to subtract two dates. The first date is set date and the second one is the current date. So i tried this code:

```
    NSString *setDateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"12:30"];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSDate *setDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:setDateString];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:setDate];
```

But it counts the interval from 1970. But I need from the current day. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want the difference between now and 1230 hrs of today. This can be done by

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components =[gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit)  fromDate:today];
[components setHour:12];
[components setMinute:30];
[components setSecond:0];
NSDate *setDate=[gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:setDate];
[gregorian release];
```

The reason it doesn't work for you is you've not given the format correctly. Alternatively, you can describe it correctly in `setDateString` by specifying all the components rather than just hour and minute.